# What are the rules on using `void` to specialize a template?

Tags: c++, templates

Here's a stripped down illustration of what I just now wrote in the wild. I wasn't really expecting it to work, but it did.

```
#include <array>

template <typename T> using Foo = std::array<T,123>;

const int FOO_SIZE = std::tuple_size<Foo<void>>::value;
```

I wasn't sure using `void` to specialize `Foo` would compile, but it did, at least in this case.

I'm not confident that this solution is portable, or if it's just a fluke because the implementation of `std::array` *happens* to be compatible with the concept of an array-of-voids, which sounds like nonsense to me.

When can I, and when can I not, use `void` to specialize a template?

Comment: You can just reorder: `constexpr ::std::size_t const foo_size{123}; template <typename T> using Foo = std::array<T, foo_size>;`

Comment: `tuple_size` doesn't instantiate its `tuple`/`array`. Instantiate `Foo<void>` would produce hard error.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find a really convincing specific set of standard wording without reproducing half the standard (:D) but I believe that this is well-defined.

The `array` constructor requires that `T` be *MoveConstructible* or *MoveAssignable*, and you're not going to be able to instantiate a `std::array<void, N>`.

But that's fine, because `std::tuple_size` doesn't need to do that, and it isn't specified to need to do that, and neither thing makes any other specific requirements that would render your code problematic.

However, this does not seem like useful code, and there is no *general* rule for when `void` can be used as a template argument. You have to look at the requirements for the specific thing you're using, in the specific context in which you're using it.

Comment: Is it specified that `tuple_size` does not instantiate the `array`, or is that just happenstance of the implementation?

Comment: @spraff It's just not specified that it does, and none of its behaviours require it to :) This isn't a happenstance of the implementation, though you could possibly argue that it is a happenstance of the specification

Answer (score 0):

It seems on the face of it surprising that this compiles at all, since array of type void are explicitly excluded by [the standard](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf#page=222) (11.3.4: 2 in the N4659 working draft linked) :

> An array can be constructed from one of the fundamental types (except
>   void), from a pointer, from a pointer to member, from a class, from an
>   enumeration type, or from another array.

And `std::array` is typically implemented directly in terms of an array, so one would expect any attempt to use it to fail.

However C++ has generous rules regarding errors in template instantiation that are not directly required in the compilation of the actual usage. In this case, I believe the code is working - and portable - since the calculation of `std::tuple_size<Foo<void>>::value` does not actually instance `Foo<void>`, but I would view such as usage as *perverse* and something you should probably be avoiding since `Foo<void>` has no validity outside of such exceptions.